# What's the cheapest way to travel from the airport to my hotel in Dublin, Ireland?

Tags: budget, public-transport, airport-transfer, dublin

I'm flying into Dublin early on a sunday morning, and I just wanted to know if I can travel from the airport to the Dun Laoghaire Harbor area without having to use a taxi.  Bus? Metro? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Cheapest? It's about a 4 hour walk ;)

Comment: Note that you can use a day travel card on the 747.

Comment: (Buy the travel card before you get on the bus.) aircoach.ie go right through, but are not the cheapest (EUR 7, IIRC).

Comment: @MarkMayo: Obviously, short of walking! :)

Comment: Curses, bet you're against hitching too ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo: Only on special occaisons & holidays... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pretty good [**page about Getting to & from Dun Laoghaire**](http://www.dun-laoghaire.com/toandfrom.html), and from that, it looks like the bus is a viable option:

> Dublin Airport is only 16 miles away. The airport is
>   serviced by buses (41, 41a, 41b, 41c) which will take you into the
>   city centre where you can transfer onto a bus to Dun Laoghaire. There
>   is also a service called AirCoach, this service is run on coaches and
>   will deliver you in comfort and speed to selected locations around the
>   city. The Dart is also accessible using the AerDart service which
>   takes you by bus to Killester Dart station.

The first **[bus 41](http://www.dublinbus.ie/en/your-journey1/timetables/All-Timetables/41/)** on Sundays leaves from Dublin Airport at **07:15**. How early are you arriving?

From the centre you can then take one of these towards Dun Laoghaire:

> 7, 7a, 8, 45a, 46a, 59, 75, 111

Some of these buses start between 7-8, some only at 09:30, and some don't run at all on Sundays. For more details, you could try the [Route Planner](http://www.dublinbus.ie/Route-Planner/).

Regarding the **price**: from the [dublinbus.ie](http://www.dublinbus.ie/) site it's not immediately clear if you can continue on the same ticket when changing to the Dun Laoghaire bus, but looking at the [list of fares](http://www.dublinbus.ie/en/Fares--Tickets/Fare-Information/Fares/), it's going to be quite cheap in every case (compared to a taxi which would cost around €50).

Comment: I'll be arriving around 9:30am.  I'm trying to get to the Royale Marine Hotel.  Do you think these buses will run on a sunday?

Comment: You should be fine then. Yes, most of them will run—see for yourself in the timetable I linked to (substitute 41 in the URL for the line you want to check).

Answer (score 8):

Those pages are well out of date.

There is [a direct bus from Dublin Airport every hour to Dun Laoghaire](http://www.aircoach.ie/media/KillineyDalkey120304.pdf). It will work out much quicker than using more than one or two modes of transport.

Cost:

- 8 euro single (Online) / 9 euro single (Pay Driver)
- 14 euro return (Online) / 15 euro return (Pay Driver)

Comment: +1, looks like the best option to me. Though certainly not the *cheapest* ;-)

Comment: We caught the bus last time we were in Dublin with no issues, so it is my recommendation as well.

Answer (score 5):

Dun Laoghaire Harbour is a little to the South East of Dublin City Centre. The Airport is to the north.

The Dublin Airport Website has a [great section on getting to/from the airport](http://www.dublinairport.com/gns/to-from-the-airport/by-bus-or-coach.aspx) which you should have a look at. I don't believe there's anything listed there that'll take you direct, but it might be worth double checking!

The option that springs to mind is to take a bus then DART (local train). You can take the [747 Bus](http://www.dublinbus.ie/en/Your-Journey1/Timetables/Airport-Services/) from the airport to the city centre, which runs pretty regularly, to Connolly Rail Station. From there, change onto the [DART](http://www.dublin.ie/transport/dart.htm), and take it to the appropriate station. (There are two serving Dun Laoghaire, so go for the one nearest your hotel!)

Answer (score 3):

For the cheapest way avoid the 747 and private buses.

Get either the 16 or the 41 to the city centre (costs €3.30; paid to the driver; exact fare, no change given). From Terminal 1 walk out the main exit from Arrivals cross the road and walk through the car park atrium. You'll find the bus stop on the other side.

Get off the bus at O'Connell Street in the city centre. It's a wide street with a large metal spike in the middle.

Walk to the end of O'Connell Street following the direction of the bus to a bridge over the river (the Liffey). Cross the bridge and turn sharp left. Walk along the left side of the street running along the river (Burgh Quay). You'll see a large elevated railbridge. The entrance to Tara Street station is just before the street goes under the elevated bridge.

Get the DART (electric train) from Tara Street station southbound to Dun Laoghaire (costs €3.25).

Comment: "Large metal spike." Epic :)